# php - merge try/catch exceptions

Tags: php

i'm trying to merge two exception objects into one.
Any idea how that works?

Here some pseudo code i have in mind:

```
$objects = array();

try {
  // do something
  throw new Exception('Error One');
} catch(Exception $e) {
  $objects[] = $e;
}


try {
  // do something
  throw new Exception('Error Two');
} catch(Exception $e) {
  $objects[] = $e;
}

if(!empty($Objetcs)) {
  // now merge objects
  $new = merge($objects);

  throw $new;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable `$objects`, so you don't need to merge.
If you want to merge two different array variable, you can use `array_merge()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `array_push`:

```
$myErrors = array();
try { throw new Exception('Error Two'); } catch( Exception $e ) {
    array_push($stack, $e);
}
```

And then simply check array length, and if it bigger than zero - concatenate error messages and rethrow them as one big chunk:

```
$l = count( $myErrors );
$long_txt = '';
if( $l > 0 ) { for( $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    if( $i > 0 ) { $long_txt .= ', '; } // add separators
    $long_txt .= $myErrors[$i]->getMessage();
}}
throw new Exception( $long_txt );
```